# Can I check data in a 3rd party app with just the handle?

Tags: delphi

I have a 3rd party app. I have a handle to the TMainDlg, and to it's child TListBox. How can I find if item 2 is selected? Right now I am (not surprisingly) running into an "EAccessViolation at address " error.

Any tips, tricks or suggestions?

```
h2 := 0;
h2 := FindWindowEx(otherApp, h2, 'TListBox', '');
lb := TListBox(h2);
ShowMessage( IntToStr( lb.Items.Count) );
```

The error occurs on the show message.

Comment: Can you provide the full access violation messages? Those addresses are important when debugging issues like this. I'm guessing `lb` is `nil`.

Comment: TListBox is a list box, use LB_GETSEL.

Comment: @Jerry, it's not important here. `FindWindowEx` returns a handle that you simply cannot cast to object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h2` is a window handle, for a window in another process. You can cast it to a `TListBox` as you did, but that does not make `h2` actually be a list box. Hence the runtime error. Essentially you lied to the compiler by claiming that `h2` was something that it is not.

You need to use some automation. You could send the other window handle list box messages and retrieve data that way. Do beware that the list box window is in a different process. So you must take care that all the messages you use marshal any data.

Here you are trying to find out how many items are in the list. Do that like so:

```
Count := SendMessage(h2, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
```

It would be prudent to perform some error checking. How do you know that `h2` is not in fact `0`?

Perhaps better would be to use the platform automation API, UI Automation.